# MuleJdbc ResultSetIterator

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am learning mule.As per the mule docs [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector+Reference) if we set streaming attribute to 'true' for select statements in mule DB connector it is returning `org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator`. Could any one please help me on how to iterate over it?

If I set the streaming to false below code is working fine and type of payload is LinkedList

```
<flow name="JDBC-OracleConfigurationWithStreaming" doc:name="JDBC-OracleConfigurationWithStreaming">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081"   path="oracleInboundWithStreaming" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:select config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database" streaming="true" fetchSize="3" maxRows="10">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT * FROM employee]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

If streaming is true and fetchsize is set then the above code is getting broken. So I removed Object-to-xml transformer . In either of the cases I am getting the following error

```
Could not find a transformer to transform
"SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator, mimeType='*/*'}"
to "SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.api.transport.OutputHandler, mimeType='*/*'}". (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException).
Message payload is of type: ResultSetIterator
```

So, I guess mule is unable to find proper transformer to iterate over ResultSetIterator.

How to iterate on the ResultSetIterator?

I am using AnypointStudio with Community Runtime 3.5

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do want to stream the DB result as the HTTP response body entity? If yes, using what format, XML?

Answer (score 0):

The `ResultSetIterator` class implements `Iterator<Map<String, Object>>` and `Closeable`, so you should be able to wrap it and expose it as an `InputStream` that the HTTP endpoint will use to build the response body entity.

Comment: I want to iterate over the db result and use the each record for other purposes. Using which message processor I can do this? Can Scripting Transformer (probably Groovy) do this? Or Are there any other options?

Comment: Have you tried with the for each message processor?

Comment: I am getting the same exception even when I am using for-each